# ZERO Device support showing in google app store for my application

Tags: android, android-studio, google-apps-marketplace

I have developed an app in Android Studio. It works fine on debug mode. I have tested it on many devices it works great. But when push it on Google App store it show me zero device support for my apk.

Let me tell you how i generate my apk

1. Make  a keystore
2. Enter key store and key password
3. select release mode in built type
4. build the apk

I know this question is asked multiple time on this forum but none of them have satisfactory answer that's why I ask it hare again please help

Here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ca.xyz.wk"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="ca.xyz.wk.app.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="ca.xyz.wk.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="ca.xyz.wk.MainActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="ca.xyz.wk.ForgotPasswordActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="ca.xyz.wk.UserRegistrationActivity"/>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is my build.grandle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ca.xzy.wk"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.roomorama:caldroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'

}
```

Comment: Try to delete <uses-sdk> in the manifest and change the target sdk to 22

Comment: why target version 22

Comment: Because it's the latest one and google recommends us to target the latest sdk

Comment: It's not working mate

Comment: is it necessary to use "com" prefix before package name as I have use "ca" prefix instead

Comment: No because I also use jp as prefix

Comment: @user3273700 have you found the solution?

Comment: @ Zeeshan Ahmed Yes I have found the solution . What I have done I simply remove all my library one by one and test the application and I found that the last library i.e 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4' causing the problem. I don't know why but after removing this library google app store accept my apk and show supported device for that. Since I use Volley library to do network request so I edit my code that use apache.commons.io and my application work fine. That all how I found solution. Sorry for late reply I hope someone will benefited with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have  found a solution . What I have done I simply remove all my library one by one and test the application and I found that the last library i.e 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4' causing the problem. I don't know why but after removing this library google app store accept my apk and show supported device for that. Since I use Volley library to do network request so I edit my code that use apache.commons.io and my application work fine. That all how I found solution. I hope someone will benefited with it.